# Procedure com IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Olá developers do stackoverflow, comecei a me aprofundar em comandos de sql a pouco tempo, estou com algum erro besta de sintaxe dessa procedure, mas por inúmeras tentativas, não consegui saná-lo, segue ai o código, ficaria muito grato se puderem me ajudar.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE procedure Inserir_Disciplina(@disciplina_nome VARCHAR(45) CHARSET UTF8)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tcc.disciplina WHERE disciplina_nome = @disciplina_nome)
THEN
    INSERT INTO tcc.disciplina(disciplina_nome) 
     VALUES(@disciplina_nome); 
END IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Opcionalmente como ficaria essa procedure com um else?

> Após Tentativas e erros...

Editei a procedure para a seguinte forma, conforme o amigo Christian Passold recomendou, fica o código meia boca, caso ajude alguém:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Inserir_Disciplina(IN p_disciplina_nome VARCHAR(45) CHARSET UTF8)
BEGIN
DECLARE numero_de_rows INT DEFAULT (SELECT count(*) FROM tcc.disciplina WHERE disciplina_nome = @disciplina_nome);

  IF(numero_de_rows = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO tcc.disciplina(disciplina_nome) 
         VALUES(p_disciplina_nome);
    SELECT "Disciplina inserida com sucesso";
    ELSE 
      SELECT "Erro, disciplina ja existente no banco de dados!";
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
```

## Delete a procedure se existir, só de segurança, após crie novamente.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Inserir_Disciplina $


CREATE PROCEDURE Inserir_Disciplina(p_disciplina_nome VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
```

## Voce pode criar uma variavel contendo a quantidade de registros do select

```
    DECLARE v_select INT DEFAULT (SELECT count(*) FROM tcc.disciplina WHERE disciplina_nome = p_disciplina_nome);
```

## Assim, Verifica se ele é maior que 0, se for, insere.

```
    IF(v_select > 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO tcc.disciplina(disciplina_nome) 
         VALUES(p_disciplina_nome);
    ELSE 
       #Do something here
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Amigo, como eu debugo em uma procedure, para quando eu chamar ela a mesma retornar uma mensagem tipo "inserido com sucesso", ou "deu erro", algo assim... ?

Comment: Cara, tem que fazer uma TRANSACTION. Fiz um exemplo para você: http://ideone.com/WxrIA8